# Is there any way to store files on Amazon EFS using Lambda Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I'm developing an API using API Gateway + Lambda Functions. The company's website is at EC2 and its images are at EFS. I have to develop one API method to upload some images to EFS, but I can't find a way to do that. Is EFS even accessible from a lambda function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, you can't. EFS is block storage, just like EBS so there's no way to access it in a lambda function's execution context. The best option would be to serve images (and other static files) from S3, which is an object store.

Comment: Thanks, @Ngenator, I thought it was the case but I hadn't found a clear answer like yours.

Answer (score 2):

AWS has released [Lambda filesystem support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-efs.html). See [these details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-filesystem.html) for configuration information, including CloudFormation and SAM templates. The file system and the Lambda function must be in the same region, and the function must be attached to the VPC, though it may be in a different account.